# Determination of geometrical isomers for chains with rings and double bonds

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

How can we determine the geometrical isomers for this compound . It contains a ring and 3  double bonds . I am confused because i was told to consider 1 ring = 1 double bond. When i tried it i got it as $2^4$ but its not the right answer . Kindly explain how to find the geometrical isomers for the compound by taking the above compound as an example.

Comment: The correct answer is 2⁴ .

Comment: You could consider 1,4-disubstituted cyclohexane = 1 double bond, if the two substituents are different. However, the 1.3-disubstituted cyclopentane is less symmetric, so you are off by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The molecule contains three $\ce{C=C}$ double bonds which may be in either (*E*), or in (*Z*) configuration, a total of $2^3$ variations if taken alone (blue rectangles).  The molecule contains two stereogenic centres, which may be either in (*R*), or in (*S*) configuration, a total of $2^2$ variations if taken alone (red rectangles):

[image]

Since you want to run the permutations on double bonds and stereogenic centers as *independent of each other*, there are $2^5 = 32$ stereo isomers possible (five parameters, two levels each).